# matplotlib.axis.axes error in mplfinance for volume

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-science, mplfinance

I am working with stock data which looks like `daily.head`

[image]

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/python/TEchAnalysis.csv')

figdims=(15,10)
fig , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figdims)
mpf.plot(daily , type='candle' , mav=(5,10,20,50,100) ,volume=True , ax=ax )
```

I am having the error

> ValueError: `volume` must be of type `matplotlib.axis.Axes`

Please can somebody explain me this error & how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you specify external axes, you should also specify axes to display the volume. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md#external-axes-method) about external axes:

> Please note the following:
>
> - Use kwarg `ax=` to pass any matplotlib Axes that you want into `mpf.plot()`
> - If you **also want to plot volume**, then you must pass in an Axes instance for the volume, so instead of `volume=True`, use volume=`<myVolumeAxesInstance><myVolumeAxesInstance>`.
> - If you specify `ax=` for `mpf.plot()` then you must also specify `ax=` for all calls to `make_addplot()`.

Comment: **This is the correct answer.**  I would also suggest, for what you appear to by trying to accomplish, **do NOT** use external axes mode.  Do ***not*** `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. And do ***not*** `figdims=(15,10)` and `fig , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figdims)`; **Rather just do:  `mpf.plot(daily,type='candle',mav=(5,10,20,50,100),volume=True,figratio=(15,10))`**

Comment: As a general rule you only want to use "external axes mode" if you are trying to accomplish something that is not otherwise already supported by mplfinance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
%matplotlib inline

df = yf.download('aapl', '2015-01-01', '2021-01-01')
df.rename(columns= {'Adj Close': 'Adj_close'}, inplace= True)
df1 = df.copy().loc['2015-01':'2015-02', :]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize= (12, 6))
fig.set_facecolor('#ffe8a8')
ax1.set_zorder(1)
ax1.grid(True, color= 'k', linestyle= '--')
ax1.set_frame_on(False)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.grid(False)
mpf.plot(df1, ax= ax1, type= 'candle', volume= ax2, xlim= (df1.index[0], 
df1.index[-1]))
plt.show()
```

It works fairly well, giving some options to customize.
This is the output:
[image]